# JHipster - execute code after function is finished

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, asynchronous, jhipster

I am using JHipster with react front end and I am having a great problem with the following:

```
function confirmRent() {
    const { rentEntity } = props;
    const entity = {
      ...rentEntity,
      ...rentValues
    };
    props.createRent(entity);
    /* execute this after createRent has finished
    const rentScsV = (res.value.status >= 200 && res.value.status < 300);
    props.history.push({
      pathname: "/",
      state: { rentScs: rentScsV }
    });
    */
  }
```

with function `createRent` located in another file

```
export const createRent: ICrudPutAction<IRent> = entity => async dispatch => {
  const result = await dispatch({
    type: ACTION_TYPES.CREATE_RENT,
    payload: axios.post(apiUrl, cleanEntity(entity))
  });
  dispatch(getEntities());
  return result;
};
```

I want to execute the commented code after `createRent` is finished.

I have tried returning a Promise in `createRent` and adding `.then()`: I get a Property 'then' does not exist.

I have tried adding a callback: It does not get executed, because `createRent` does not have access to history.

I have tried adding `await` in `confirmRent` like this

```
async function confirmRent() {
...
await props.createRent(entity);
/* execute the rest */
}
```

I get a `Unexpected 'await' of a non-Promise (non-"Thenable") value` error.

From what I can see, I can not change `createRent` signature, because a lot of other functions in other modules depend from it. Does anyone have an idea on how to resolve this issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

@lsti115 last comment gave me an idea so I tried this

```
new Promise(resolve => {
  resolve(props.createRent(entity));
}).then(res => {
  const rentScsV = ((res as any).value.status >= 200 && (res as any).value.status < 300);
  props.history.push({
    pathname: "/",
    state: { rentScs: rentScsV }
  });
});
```

and it worked.

Is this considered bad coding in any way?

Also I had to cast `res as any` because the compiler gave me this error 
`Property 'value' does not exist on type '{}'`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what JHipster is, but if I see correctly, `createRent` is not an asynchronous function itself, it just returns one that is, so the `props.createRent(entity);` call does actually get executed before the code that comes after it.

[If I wrote `const add = x => y => x + y` instead of `const add = (x, y) => x + y`, then I would have to call it as `add(5)(3)` instead of `add(5, 3)`.]

To actually utilize it, you would need to store the value it returns, on which you could use `.then()`, like for example:

```
const cr = props.createRent(entity);
cr(dispatch).then(res => {
  const rentScsV = (res.value.status >= 200 && res.value.status < 300);
  props.history.push({
    pathname: "/",
    state: { rentScs: rentScsV }
  });
)
```

or you can skip the intermediary variable and call the returned function immediately:

```
props.createRent(entity)(dispatch).then(res => {
  const rentScsV = (res.value.status >= 200 && res.value.status < 300);
  props.history.push({
    pathname: "/",
    state: { rentScs: rentScsV }
  });
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I add your modification, it raises this error: 
`Cannot find name 'dispatch'. ts(2304)`

Comment: You need to provide an actual dispatch parameter, I just put the name there. That is probably framework specific, so right now I cannot help you with that.
(It is also a possibility that you need to return the function itself and not run in immediately, as another function will be able to provide a dispatch to it. If this is similar to Redux, it's likely that this will be the case.)

Comment: Thanks again. Can you please develop more your last solution (return the function itself)? I'm sorry but I don't quite get it.

Comment: In certain frameworks that have a central management, you should not do actions yourself, but rather prepare (encapsulate) them as functions that result in the desired effect and pass them to a higher order function that will provide them with their required parameters and execute them.